# Android 6 does not register BroadcastReceiver for music events

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-6.0-marshmallow

In Android 4 all works fine. In Android 6 the `onReceive()` of the dynamically registered `BroadcastReceiver` is not called. I register the receiver with this code:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("com.android.music.metachanged");
filter.addAction("com.android.music.playstatechanged");
filter.addAction("com.android.music.playbackstatechanged");
filter.addAction("com.android.music.playbackcomplete");
filter.addAction("com.android.music.queuechanged");
filter.addAction("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
a.registerReceiver(receiver = new AudioBroadcastReceiver(), filter); //a is Activity
```

This code definitely works - I checked. And receiver looks like this:

```
class AudioBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ...
    }
}
```

They say it is needed to dynamically give special permissions to the application before registering `BroadcastReceiver`. But I cannot find how - what should I request with `Manifest.permission.`? for this case. I just want receive signals when player changes music track. What is *dangerous* in this?

Comment: Those are undocumented, unsupported broadcasts. There is no requirement for any device to have any app that sends them, for any version of Android.

Comment: But the application definitely SENDS those broadcasts. Marshmallow just does not deliver them. Or does not register filter. I think this is a BUG. OS must deliver each signal being sent by any application - it can be "internal" signal for other application parts.

Comment: "But the application definitely SENDS those broadcasts" -- and your proof of this is, what, exactly? Have you tried sending them yourself, such as via `adb shell am`?

Comment: Damn... the new music player in Android 6 does not send broadcasts. I tried install old one player and another one new - all works fine with both of them. I wanted create my own player at long time before - looks like this is time to start it.

Answer (score 0):

You are relying upon undocumented, unsupported broadcasts. Some player apps might use these. Others might not. Different versions of the same player might or might not use these.

Do not assume that any given device will have a player that supports these broadcasts, or that the user's chosen player will support these broadcasts.